# Base Class Distribution Issue

Tags: c#, properties, parameters

So I'm currently writing an API, but I've hit a road block in construction.  The issue is a series of values will constantly be called throughout, which requires a lot of parameters to be constantly pushed into series of classes and methods throughout the API.

Which is not very elegant nor practical.  As it will induce a large amount of extra code.

My thought was originally was this:

```
public class CustomerProfile
{
    public string ParentSite { get; private set; }
    public string DynamicSite { get; private set; }
    public string SiteDb { get; private set; }

    public CustomerProfile(string parentSite, string dynamicSite, string siteDb)
    {
          if (string.IsEmptyOrNull(parentSite) && 
                    string.IsEmptyOrNull(dynamicSite) &&
                    string.IsEmptyOrNull(siteDb))
           {
                 throw new Exception("Error Message: + "\n"
                     + "Null value exception...");
           }
           else
           {
                ParentSite = parentSite;
                DynamicSite = dynamicSite;
                SiteDb = siteDb;
           }
    }
}
```

So my thought was to have a nice class that will set the properties, will act like a container for these repeatable values.

However, my issue seems to come from the next class.

```
public class Configuration
{
        public CustomerProfile profile;
        public Configuration(string parentSite, string dynamicSite, string siteDb)
        {
              CustomerProfile profile = new CustomerProfile(parentSite, dynamicSIte, siteDb);
        }
}
```

This now works throughout the class I would just use `profile.SiteDb` or another property that resides within it.

But is this really the best approach?

I could use simple inheritance, but I'm not really sure that is cleaner or more efficient.  Any thoughts on the matter would be terrific?

Is this approach the more ideal to pass property values from one class to another, as it will be used throughout several and several methods as well.  I was looking for the cleanest way to invoke.

So my question is:

> Out of all the ways to pass properties, what way is the best and why? 
>   I thought this approach would be best but as I begin to use it
>   throughout it seems like it may not be the most ideal.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I have a concrete answer for you, but I'd change the `Configuration` constructor to take a `CustomerProfile` as an input parameter. `Configuration` doesn't know/care about _how_ to make a `CustomerProfile`; if you add a 4th property, now you have to update it in two places. Also, consider making the `public CustomerProfile Profile { get; private set; }` rather than a public field. EDIT: Also, this is a pretty broad question, might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is a good suggestion, so when the second class is built they are physically passing an object with those variables filled.

Comment: Yup. And if `CustomerProfile` is mutable, then those changes are propagated to all other classes referencing that single object. What this all is is essentially constructor injection. Maybe what you're really after is a nice method for handling dependency injection. (I'm a fan of constructor injection myself, definitely look it up!)

Comment: Yeah, Dependency Injection is an approach I'm sort of after but not exactly.  You are correct though I was looking for a way to inject the values to each class at creation.  I'll delve further into it though.